# MariaDB system versioning allow epoch format of timestamp

Tags: mariadb

For MariaDB system versioning, I created the table as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS talentTable(x) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

After inserting a few items, I got as below:

```
 SELECT keyCol, valCol, ROW_START, ROW_END FROM talentTable;

| x | ROW_START                  | ROW_END                    |
+---+----------------------------+-----------------------------
| 1 | 2019-04-28 11:19:32.545138 | 2038-01-19 11:14:07.999999 |
| 2 | 2019-04-28 11:21:36.768530 | 2038-01-19 11:14:07.999999 |
+---+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

My question is, can I make MariaDB to store the timestamp in row_start and row_end in epoch format when the table is created in the first step? For example, for x1 row start, i want to store the time as `1556421572` instead of `2019-04-28 11:19:32.545138`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that just add `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ROW_START)` will do.

Comment: You can either do that dynamically in the `SELECT`, or store it into a `DECIMAL(16,6)` column.